# PostgreSQLのバックアップをC#で行いたい

Tags: c#, postgresql

**やりたいこと**
現在、LinuxサーバーのDBのバックアップをクライアント(windows)から行うシステムを作りたいと思っているのですが、躓いてしまったため質問させていただきます。
色々と調べつつ、下記のようなコードを書いたのですが、実行してもバックアップファイルは生成されません。
どの部分を直すことによって正常に動作しますでしょうか。

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            //Processオブジェクトを作成
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = @"set PGPASSWORD=***&& pg_dump -Fc -v --host=192.***.**.*** --username=postgres --dbname=System -f C:\Users\---\Desktop\database.dump";
            startInfo.Verb = "runas";
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
 }
```

コマンドプロンプトで直接"**set PGPASSWORD=*****"、"**pg_dump -Fc -v --host=192.***.**.*** --username=postgres --dbname=System -f C:\Users---\Desktop\database.dump**"と入力すると、バックファイルを作ることができました。

Comment: && pg_dumpを& pg_dumpとしたときはどうなりますか？CMDで複文を記述するときに区切る記号は＆ひとつでよいと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMDで複文を記述するときに区切る記号は＆ひとつでよいと思います。

```
C:\Users\XXXX>SET AAA=aaa&echo %AAA%
aaa
```

それでもダメな場合は、コマンドプロンプトでうまくいくのですから、batファイルに記述して、CMDで実行してはいかがでしょうか？

事前にファイルを作成できないなら、batファイルを新規に作成し、環境変数PGPASSWORDの設定とpg_dumpを実行するコマンドを書き込み、batファイルを実行し、batファイルを削除すればよいと思います。

Comment: startInfo.Arguments = @"set PGPASSWORD=**&""C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin\pg_dump.exe"" -Fc -v --host=192.**.**.**--username=postgres --dbname=System -f C:\Users\**\**\database.dump"; 「&」を１つにしてみたり、dumpをフルパスで実行してみたりもしたのですが「例外がスローされました: 'System.InvalidOperationException' (System.dll の中)
System.InvalidOperationException: StandardOut がリダイレクトされていないか、またはプロセスが開始されていませんでした。」というエラーが出てしまいます。batファイルを使ったやり方で一度やってみます。

Comment: batファイルを使用したらアプリからdumpファイルの生成を行うことができました！しかし、ところどころ文字化けがあるのですが、このままでもリストアは可能なのでしょうか・・・

Comment: ↑すみません。こちらはエンコードオプションを付けることで解決しました。